# MySQL two columns complex query to implement chat

Tags: mysql

Let me explain what we are about.

```
table:
from_id    to_id      time
1          2          0
1          3          1
2          1          1
3          1          0
```

What I want to get is :

```
table:
from_id     to_id    time
2           1        1
1           3        1
```

So we are checking if from_id column and to_id column have the same values. Like 1->2 or 2->1 (there could multiple with the different time) we find the latest one of all. And get that. Same goes for all other things.

What I've already tried didn't work and also if I post them more people will be misled, so I rather not do that. I thought it would be simple but it wasn't for me.

The real example is:

[image]

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please _always_ provide your attempts. This will help differentiate your question from someone who made no effort at all - unfortunately we get hundreds of those every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to find the latest message in a chat between to people

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from `table` t
where not exists (
  select 1 from `table`
  where created_at > t.created_at and 
    ((from_id = t.from_id and to_id = t.to_id) or (from_id = t.to_id and to_id = t.from_id))
);
```

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.from_id, t.to_id, t.created_at, t.updated_at
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by least(from_id, to_id), greatest(from_id, to_id) order by created_at desc) rn
  from `table`
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Wow that seemed to do the trick.Would you please explain the where not exists? and how it works with the select statement inside?Just that part the rest is beautiful and obvious.

Comment: The subquery searches for a row (any row) that contains the same ids as the table's current row (maybe interchanged from and to) that has a created_at later than the table's current row. If one is not found then the current row from the table is returned because this is the latest for the 2 ids.

Comment: Lord of the SQL Ring :)